# 70's sci-fi book where the Earth has become so polluted, people wear gas masks outside; scientists find a temporary fix by expanding the atmosphere

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a sci-fi book, probably from the 70's, about an Earth in which the air is very polluted and people have to wear gas masks to go out.

Earth looks like it has reached crisis point when some boffins discover a temporary solution to do with expanding the atmosphere or something.

On the version I read the cover was a man in a gas mask.

Answer (score 9):

How about the [*The Sheep Look Up*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheep_Look_Up) by John Brunner.  Published in 1972 and nominated for a Nebula.  Fell out of print but appears to be available again.

[image: Cover Art]  [image: Cover of first edition]

From the [Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932100016):

> An enduring classic, this book offers a dramatic and prophetic look at the potential consequences of the escalating destruction of Earth. In this nightmare society, air pollution is so bad that gas masks are commonplace. Infant mortality is up, and everyone seems to suffer from some form of ailment. The water is polluted, and only the poor drink from the tap. The government is ineffectual, and corporate interests scramble to make a profit from water purifiers, gas masks, and organic foods.
>
> Environmentalist Austin Train is on the run. The Trainites, environmental activists and sometime terrorists, want him to lead their movement. The government wants him in jail, or preferably, executed. The media wants a circus. Everyone has a plan for Train, but Train has a plan of his own.

Comment: Amazon has some of Brunner's work a Kindle books, but oddly not this one.

Comment: I thought of this when I saw the question, but Train's solution doesn't involve expanding the atmsophere, even temporarily.  It's rather more, uh, direct.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another possibility - "Population Doomsday" (1970) by Don Pendleton. I never read this but I remember the cover had a man in a gas mask.

[image: Population Doomsday cover]

From [this Amazon review](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0523003293):

> It's January 1989 and a new President, Royal Hackett, takes office in the midst of an eco-catastrophe. The population of the US has reached 390 million and there is widespread environmental degradation. Air pollution in the cities is so bad that people are obliged to wear gas masks when out-of-doors. The rest of the world is in as bad a shape (or worse).
>
> The main character is a reporter named Bill Vance, who knows the President well enough to be invited to attend White House planning sessions on measures to address the national dilemma. Vance soon finds himself sent to Gary, Indiana, where a disastrous smog event has left most of the city's population dead or dying. The scenes in which Vance, attired in a cumbersome space suit, wanders the darkened streets of the city only to see mounds of the gasping dying, are effective.

Comment: Could be, wish I could find a synopsis. +1

Comment: Did you check amazon reviews?

Comment: Did an exhaustive search but can't find any detailed synopsis.  Hopefully, the questioner will eventually respond and let us know :) BTW - Welcome to the site !!

Comment: I believe **Population Doomsday** is the book the original poster was looking for since it does does involve "expanding the atmosphere or something." I remembered the protagonist being in Gary, Indiana, people having to wear gas masks outside, and the solution to cleaning the atmosphere. There is a 2014 posting on the Climate & Capitalism website:  [Population pulp fiction: A failed prophecy from 1970](https://climateandcapitalism.com/2014/05/07/population-pulp-fiction/) about the book. What I didn't remember at all was that the main point of the book was over population, not air pollution!